# Nginx error 502 Bad Gateway caused because of many 'Set-Cookie'

Tags: nginx, cookies, varnish

I am having problems to deploy an application using Varnish and Nginx while doing a *POST* request.

The log below was got from the *varnishlog* command:

[image]

As you guys can see, looks like Nginx is trying to create the same cookie many times. I checked my application and we are not setting the same cookie value twice.

I tried to apply the follow settings on Nginx, but did not change the result:

```
proxy_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffers 4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 32k;
```

And I am always getting:

[image]

Varnish settings:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {

if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD" &&
    req.method != "PUT" && req.method != "POST" &&
    req.method != "TRACE" && req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
    req.method != "DELETE") {
        return(pipe);
} /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */

if(req.method == "POST"){
         return (pass);
}

if (req.url ~ "61646D696E2D646576") {
        return (pass);
}

if (req.url ~ "payzen") {
        return (pass);
}

if ((req.url ~ "REFRESH")) {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "REFRESH", "");
        return (purge);
}

if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache")
{
        return(pass);
}

return(hash);

}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

if(beresp.status == 500) {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        return (deliver);
}

if(beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 302) {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        return (deliver);
}

if (beresp.status >= 200 && beresp.status < 400 && (bereq.method
== "PUT" || bereq.method == "POST" || bereq.method == "DELETE")) {
            ban("obj.http.X-Invalidated-By ~ " + bereq.http.X-Invalidates);
    }

if (!beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
       unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
       unset beresp.http.cookie;
}

if (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
}

# IF IT'S SYMFONY DEBUG (DEV) MODE
if (beresp.http.X-Debug-Token) {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
}

    return(deliver);

}

sub vcl_deliver {

if (obj.hits > 0){
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT";
} else {
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
}

}
```

Nginx config:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server_tokens off;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    server {
        listen       localhost:8080;
        include /etc/nginx/redirects.nginx;

        location / {

        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
           return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
        }


         resolver 172.31.0.2 valid=10s;
         set $backend_upstream "http://my-server:80";
         proxy_pass $backend_upstream;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       }
    }

}
```

Any idea where that problem comes from?

Thanks! :)

Comment: The outlined cookie thing is normal - it means you're doing some cookie manipulations in the Varnish VCL (i.e. unset, cleanup, etc.) The 502 you get with nginx is only related to your PHP-FPM setup - it's likely pointing to the wrong socket file or wrong port.

Comment: I posted the Varnish settings, maybe something missing/wrong over there?

Comment: Post your nginx config

Comment: Nginx config posted

Comment: Thanks all you guys, I found the issue. It was because Elastic Beanstalk with Docker uses Nginx to transmit data to Docker, that Nginx config default by AWS was missing buffer parameters :)